# Add custom body tag if product is out of stock

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have searched endlessly for this but I am yet to find a solution.

I have found ways to add custom classes through functions but can't seem to achieve through woocommerce where a custom class is added on the single product page when a product is out of stock.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('body_class', 'SE_314220_custom_outofstock_class');

 function SE_314220_custom_outofstock_class ($classes) {

  global $post;
  if($post->post_type !="product")
    return $classes;
  $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
  if($product->get_stock_quantity() ==0)
    $classes[] = 'OUT-OF-STOCK';
  return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the code from @Adnrea Somovigo and customize it, to display body classes, based on stock_status, not on stock_quantity. So this should work also for in-stock, on-backorder and out-of-stock stock statuses.

Stock quantity is not the correct parameter, because backorder products could have negative quantity (for example -6 pieces on stock) and products with 0 pieces could be either out-of-stock, or on-backorder.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'lava_stock_class');

 function lava_stock_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type !="product")
        return $classes;
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    if($product->get_stock_status() == 'outofstock') {
        $classes[] = 'outofstock';
    } elseif($product->get_stock_status() == 'onbackorder') {
        $classes[] = 'onbackorder';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'instock';
    }

    return $classes;  
}
```